# Simple PHP login script save?

Tags: php, security, authentication

I'm doing this simple tutorial on the following website:

http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html

Is the code that they use safe or could a hacker possibly enter somehow?

Thanks

PS: If there are problems, what are they, how can I prevent them. Is there maybe an even better tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That script protects against SQL Injection attacks but could possibly be vulnerable to an XSS (Cross Site Scripting) attack. You should add enforcement of allowed characters on at least the username to keep out anything but alphanumeric and a limited set of punctuation. For ease of use on your users, you should do this check in javascript to make the site more responsive but you must do it in the PHP code to be truly protected against XSS.

Comment: Ok, thanks Cory. Other than that do you think it could be used on a live website?

Comment: Yeah, it should be fine otherwise